# Wordpress PHP: don't want menu on front page, trying 'if (!is_front_page())'

Tags: php, wordpress

My question is about how to use 'if' when I don't want to see header on front page? Or do you have any other solution?

```
   <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <div id="page" class="site">
     <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'shapely' ); ?></a>
   **<?php if (!is_front_page()) : ?>**
   <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <div class="nav-container">
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    //lines of code
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </div>
    </header><!-- #masthead -->
    **<?php endif; ?>**
    <div id="content" class="main-container">
    <?php ( is_page_template('template-home.php') ) ? '' : shapely_top_callout(); ?>
    <section class="content-area <?php echo ( get_theme_mod('top_callout', true ) ) ? '' : ' pt0 ' ?>">
      <div id="main" class="<?php echo ( !is_page_template( 'template-home.php' )) ? 'container': ''; ?>" role="main">
            <div class="row">
```

Comment: is your code not working now?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Still having a problem with it :(

Comment: Ok, I've nailed it with this:
`<?php if (!is_front_page()): ?>
           <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
// lines of code
            </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
<?php endif; ?>`
I really don't know how it happened oO

Answer (score 3):

You can create a diffrent header and include it as per your need :

**code in page.php**

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) :
    get_header( 'home' );
else :
    get_header();
endif;
?>
```

**Create header-home.php**

create a file with name header-home.php Copy header.php and remove nav from header.php code.

```
<html>
<head>
<!--- Except Nav menu all code will be here -->
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for help.
Now there is no menu anywhere, I used following code in page.php to be sure:
`<?php
if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) :
    get_header( 'home' );
else :
    get_header();
endif;
?>`

Answer (score -1):

create a template file.

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Custom Front Page
*/ 
?>
```

copy contents required into that template file under the page declaration.

edit front page and select your custom page template.

Comment: *the <header> is part of the header.php* thats not really through

Comment: well i jumped the gun there... I should say usually, still template file would make the most sense, thats what they are for.

Comment: why we create a new template for just only displaying menu ? you understand what i am try to saying. @ChristianCaltabiano